# Is the possibility of Harry being named Elvendork from the books?

Tags: harry-potter

I've seen in multiple fanfictions and other places the joke that Sirius and/or James wanted to name Harry Elvendork, stating that it was unisex. Is this from canon or Word of God, or just something created by the fans but spread widely?

Comment: Incidentally, a [search](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=Elvendork) of the HP Wikia shows only articles related to the prequel, so it's unlikely JK Rowling went on to say it might have been Harry's name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The name Elvendork is from the [Harry Potter prequel](http://copiedtext.blogspot.com/2010/10/harry-potter-prequel-by-jk-rowling-2008.html) (see [Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_Prequel)).

> ‘Names?’ repeated the long-haired driver. ‘Er – well, let’s see. There’s Wilberforce… Bathsheba… Elvendork…’

And near the end:

> ‘Yeah, nice meeting you!’ said James. ‘And don’t forget: Elvendork! It’s unisex!’

It was written by Rowling for auctioning off for charity. I don't know whether most fans consider it canon. If you want to consider it canon, then do so. It doesn't say that they were going to name Harry Elvendork, but it *does* refer to it as unisex.

Comment: Haha, I seriously had *no idea* that this existed. +1 for knowing your Elventrivia ;)

Comment: @Slytherincess I actually just [searched](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=Elvendork) HP Wikia. (But I *had* read the prequel before).

Comment: I actually haven't read the prequel -- do you know where I can get my hands on it? Is it online anywhere?

Comment: @Slytherincess I linked to a copy of it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't checked your links, but will do so. :)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that JKR name-checked it later; https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/622011824624521217

Answer (score 1):

I've been in Harry Potter fandom since 2002 and I've never heard the term "Elvendork" in relation to Harry. Seems more appropriate for Legolas, were Legolas to have a ridiculous nickname.

There is this from *Half-Blood Prince*, though, which makes me laugh:

> ‘Have you ever heard of someone called the Half-Blood Prince?’
>   ‘The Half-Blood what?’
>   ‘Prince,’ said Harry, watching him closely for signs of recognition.
>   ‘There are no wizarding princes,’ said Lupin, now smiling. ‘Is this a title you’re thinking of adopting? I should have thought being the “Chosen One” would be enough.’
>   ‘It’s nothing to do with me!’ said Harry indignantly.
>   <sub>*Half-Blood Prince* - page 315 - Bloomsbury - chapter 16, *A Very Frosty Christmas*</sub>

Also, Draco calling Harry "'The Boy Who Scored" ... or whatever it is they're calling you these days ...'" is a bit amusing.

I don't recall "Elvendork" in any of the Harry Potter books, nor has the term come up in any J.K. Rowling interview I've ever heard or read. I don't know how widely spread it really is, but if it is ubiquitous it's probably propogated by the fans at this point. That said, I encourage you all to throw your votes to Ike! :D